# GitHub Actions - Add Azure Artifact Feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, github-actions

I'm trying to add my custom Azure artifact feed to a GitHub action build. I've added a line which adds the package as a source.

```
run: dotnet nuget add source ${{ env.nuget_feed_source }} --name ${{ env.nuget_feed_name }} --username az --password ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTKEY }} --store-password-in-clear-text
```

However, when I go to restore the package, I get an error saying it can't find the package

> error NU1101: Unable to find package *****. No packages exist with this id in source(s): ****, nuget.org

To me, this looks like it's trying to search the default NuGet feed rather than my custom.

I tried adding a `nuget.config` file but then I got the error:

> error: The name specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Provide a unique name.

If I create a `nuget.config` with just the default feed, and manually add my package, it is successful but I still get a similar error:

> error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source ***

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Adam

```
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Add custom nuget source
      run: dotnet nuget add source ${{ env.nuget_feed_source }} --name ${{ env.nuget_feed_name }} --username az --password ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTKEY }} --store-password-in-clear-text
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Deploy to Azure Function App
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.InsertPair_e2f5 }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the personal access token I was using didn't have the correct permissions to access the feed :/

Enabling all access fixed my issue